# Setting object random position on x-axis

Tags: android

I am creating an app that would display an object randomly on the x-axis, but somehow my app crashes on start.

It works when I use **DisplayMetrics**, but it gets the width of the entire screen. I would want to get the width of a **LAYOUT**. But the app crashes on start when I try to retrieve the layout width and set a random position

I have a feeling that the **TIMER** starts before it can retrieve the **LAYOUT WIDTH**. That's why it crashes

This is code:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    frame = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);

    screenWidth = frame.getWidth();

    r = new Random();

    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    goDown();
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 20);

//FUNCTIONS FOR IT TO GO DOWN
public void goDown() {
    //LAYOUT WIDTH
    frameWidth = screenWidth;   

    //DISPLAYING RANDOM X POSITION
    newXposition = r.nextInt(frameWidth);

    //SKULLS FUNCTIONS
    skullY += skullSpeed;
    if(skullY > frameHeight)
    {
        skullY = -100.0f;
        skullX = newXposition - skull.getWidth();
    }

    skull.setX(skullX);
    skull.setY(skullY);

  }
```

and this is my LOGCAT:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.gin.myapplication, PID: 8786
              java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0
                  at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:182)
                  at com.example.gin.myapplication.MainActivity.goDown(MainActivity.java:91)
                  at com.example.gin.myapplication.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:74)
```

Thanks in advance for any help! :D

Comment: Where are you calling goDown()?

Comment: @Elinor sorry I forgot to change that. It is goDown really. haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android , views are drawn at much later stage. Until then any getter methods for view dimensions return zero. You need to wait for the views to be drawn on the screen before reading its values.
You can do it in two ways

**Add layout listener in viewtreeobserver**

```
frame.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new 
ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            frame.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            screenWidth = frame.getHeight(); //height is ready
        }
    });
```

**Attach Post Runnable**

```
frame.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            screenWidth = frame.getHeight(); //height is ready
        }
    });
```

Comment: I used the layout listener and added the timer within the layout listener. The timer was causing the problem since the timer will run and the value of the layout width has not been retrieved. haha. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Note:  You can eliminate the timer completely by using frame.postDelayed() method